# Javascript timezone offset does'nt reflect local machine's timezone

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, web

Facing an unique issue, One of the users machine does'nt reflect the local timezone.

User Machine's timezone is GMT (London) and for current date(Sep 06 2012) the offset should have been -60 (BST), which is GMT+1. But it returns 0 UTC offset, and date is also reflecting in UTC  which is kind of weird.

```
window.alert("Current Local Desktop Date \"" + new Date() + "\" whose offset difference is " + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() + " mins from UTC");
```

Is there anything needs to be updated in windows ??

Ruled out possibilities:

1. Daylight saving settings in Date&Time service. Because if this setting isnt checked then the taskbar time should have been different. But the task bar time reflects in BST.
2. Browser issue --> Tried in both IE & Chrome. Both returns the same.

Comment: My first guess would be that the PC's timezone is incorrect itself.

Comment: How could that be.. if its displaying the right time in the taskbar ??

Comment: You can calibrate the time manually regardless of timezone. In fact, it's highly probable that is the situation, since it is easier to change the time than the timezone. I would advise that you check the computer's timezone directly yourself.

Comment: I remotely logged on to that pc and verified by myself. Everything looks good, the time is displayed in BST(GMT+1). But the browser/javascript doesnot return the appropriate offset. It always returns in UTC. I doubt there could be a windows registry settings that might be preventing, but still googling around to find an answer.

Comment: A quick search of the various *Internet Explorer* settings did not result in anything related to timezone. You can check the timezone by running the following in the browser address bar: `javascript:alert(new Date)` (on mine it said `"Mon Sep 10 19:27:58 UTC+0200 2012"`, which is correct).

Comment: Thx Christian, If you see my post thats what i did at the first place. The alert returned in UTC but the local time is in BST(GMT+100). Anyways desktop experts tried to look for some solution, but didnt result anything positive. They created a similar build as that of the user in another pc, but that resulted fine with expected behavior. I saw some timezone settings in registry when running windows as a terminal server. Will let you know if i find anything positive.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't have been of better help. I haven't experienced this issue before.